# Can a Google App-Engine Objectify entity have multiple @Id fields?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I wonder if an Objectify entity have multiple IDs.

I don't fully know how an `@Index` works, but I suppose it's also used for sorting purposes.

I have an entity with two fields that it has unique compared to others, so they could both be the `@Id`, but they are less than an `@Index` since they should not be used for range or inequality queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an `@Entity` annotated class can have only one `@Id` field that can be:

- `long`
- `Long`
- `String`

Only `Long` type will autogenerate a value when saved.

You can build your own object that has a `toString()` representation that respect the sort order of your two unique fields. 
The `toString()` value can be used to a `String` type `@Id` field like

```
@Id
String myCustomId;
```

This field have to be set to your new entity before saving it.